# Best way to change React state at <App /> level based on sub-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-component

I have a React app that has a top-level `<App />` component (built starting from create-react-app). My top level component looks something like this:

```
<Header title={this.state.appTitle} theme={this.state.theme} />
<Switch>
  {routes.map((route, index) => <Route key={index} {...route} />)}
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

(`routes` is an array of { component:, to: } objects). Each component rendered by `<Route>` uses a sub-component called `<Page>` where I set a title and wrap some content:

```
<Page title="About Us">
  <p>Content here</p>
</Page>
```

Sometimes a page might use a different theme which I want to apply to the `<Header />` when that page is being viewed:

```
<Page title="About Us" theme="alt">
```

What I'm looking to do is change `appTitle` and `theme` state in `<App />` when each component is rendered. What is the best way to do this? Using one of React's life-cycle hooks? Some other method to change the "top-level" state? How can I pass an action down to these components *through* the react-router `<Route>` component if so?

Comment: Do you want `this.state`/the props being passed to the header to update based on the props being passed to `<Page />`?

Comment: @paulruescher effectively, yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to each component, and call that function when each child gets mounted, with [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method.

```
<Switch>
  {routes.map((route, index) => {
    const Comp = route.component;
    return <Route
      key={index}
      { ...route}
      // overwrite the component prop with another component
      component={
        (routeProps) => (
          <Comp
            {...routeProps}
            childHasMounted={() => this.setState({ name: route.name })}
          />
        ) 
      }
    />
  })}
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>

// child.js
class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.childHasMounted();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flip the structure on its head. Have every "page" component control their own layout.

Make a layout higher order component (function that takes a component class and returns a component class):

```
function LayoutHOC({ title, theme, component: ContentComponent }) {
    return class LayoutWrapper extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Header title={title} theme={theme} />
                    <Page title={title} theme={them}>
                        <ContentComponent {...this.props} />
                    </Page>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Make the folder structure domain specific, as in `pages/about/MyAboutPage.jsx` to hold the main component content.

Then make `pages/about/index.js` and export the content component wrapped in the layout higher order component.

`index.js`:

```
import MyAboutPage from './MyAboutPage';
export default LayoutHOC({ title: 'my title', theme: 'alt', component: MyAboutPage })
```

Then in your routes you can `import About from './pages/about'` (since it uses index.js you don't have to worry about nested folder structure).

The downside is you have to create an index.js for each domain/route. The upside is your content component doesn't know about its layout, and every page/route can controll its own header/footer however you want.

This pattern is stolen from [this React boilerplate project](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/tree/master/src/routes/home)

Comment: This is awesome. I guess I was concerned about rerendering the header for each title change. For example, I wanted the background of the header to animate between themes when it changes. Would something like still be possible with a HOC?

Comment: Hmmmm, if you do it entirely with CSS animations, I suspect so, but i'm not sure. If you do it with Javascript animations in the component or CSSTransitionGroup...I have no idea! :O